# Javascript html table hidding columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table

I have developed this neat little piece of code which given an element and a properly formatted table, creates a dropdown menu on the element which allows the user to toggle view of columns.

I cannot figure out how to make the changes (which columns to stay hidden) persists on page change, as it is a usual pattern to have a table on a page with pagination.

fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mssrq8ah/

my html markup:

```
<table id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>h1</th><th>h2</th><th>h3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>a1</td><td>a2</td><td>a3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>b1</td><td>b2</td><td>b3</td>
        </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<button id="list">drop</button>
```

my js function:

```
table_hide("#list","#table")
function table_hide( button , table)
         {

             jQuery(button).attr("data-toggle","dropdown");
             jQuery(button).addClass("dropdown-toggle");
             jQuery(button).wrap("<div class='btn-group'>");
             var list = "";
             jQuery("thead").find("tr").first().find("th").each(function(index,element){
                 list = list + "<li>" +
                "<div class='checkbox col-md-6'><label><input type='checkbox' checked value='"+index+"' class='td_hide'>"+jQuery(element).text()+"</label></div>"+
                "</li>";
             });
             jQuery(button).after("<ul class='dropdown-menu col-md-12'>"+list+"</ul>");


            jQuery(".td_hide").on("click",function(){
                        var target_column = jQuery(this).val();
                        jQuery("tr").each(function(index , element){

                            jQuery(this).find("th , td").eq(target_column).toggle();
                        });   
                });

            jQuery(".dropdown-menu").find("select , .ws-popover-opener , .step-control").on("click",function(e){
                e.stopPropagation();
                });
         }
```

if at all possible i would like to avoid any more needed libraries as i intent to use it on CMS, and jQuery/bootstrap is the standard these days.

Comment: `how to make the changes (which columns to stay hidden) persists on page change`... If you're interested in persisting anything, you need to look at using local storage, cookies or a database. When you refresh the page, all JS data will be lost

Comment: I would suggest you to save the state (visible or not) of all the columns in a localStorage and after page load you read from that localStorage and set the visibilities. localStorage is easy to use - just do localStorage.setItem and localStorage.getItem. You can get the current state of the column by doing jQuery("tr").first().find('th, td').is(':visible')

Comment: Thanks very much guys, i posted below my final solution

Answer (score 0):

Voila!

thanks for the local storage thingie, really helped me out.

https://jsfiddle.net/mssrq8ah/1/

```
<table id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>h1</th><th>h2</th><th>h3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>a1</td><td>a2</td><td>a3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>b1</td><td>b2</td><td>b3</td>
        </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<button id="list">drop</button>
```

javascript

```
table_hide("#list","#table")
function table_hide( button , table)
         {
             var cookie_domain = window.location.href + query_params("page")+"hidden";

             jQuery(button).attr("data-toggle","dropdown");
             jQuery(button).addClass("dropdown-toggle");
             jQuery(button).wrap("<div class='btn-group'>");
             var list = "";
             jQuery("thead").find("tr").first().find("th").each(function(index,element){
                 list = list + "<li>" +
                "<div class='checkbox col-md-6'><label><input type='checkbox' checked value='"+index+"' class='td_hide'>"+jQuery(element).text()+"</label></div>"+
                "</li>";
             });
             jQuery(button).after("<ul class='dropdown-menu col-md-12'>"+list+"</ul>");

             jQuery("thead").find("tr").first().find("th").each(function(index , element){
                    if(localStorage.getItem(cookie_domain+index) == "true")
                    {
                        jQuery(".td_hide").eq(index).attr('checked', false);
                        jQuery("tr").each(function(index2 , element2){
                            jQuery(this).find("th , td").eq(index).toggle();
                        });
                    }
                });
            jQuery(".td_hide").on("click",function(){
                        var target_column = jQuery(this).val();
                        jQuery("tr").each(function(index , element){
                            if(jQuery(this).find("th , td").eq(target_column).first().css('display') == 'none')
                            {
                                localStorage.setItem(cookie_domain+target_column, 'false');
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                localStorage.setItem(cookie_domain+target_column, 'true');
                            }
                            jQuery(this).find("th , td").eq(target_column).toggle();
                        });   
                });

            jQuery(".dropdown-menu").find("select , .ws-popover-opener , .step-control").on("click",function(e){
                e.stopPropagation();
                });
         }

 function query_params(name){
               if(name=(new RegExp('[?&]'+encodeURIComponent(name)+'=([^&]*)')).exec(location.search))
                  return decodeURIComponent(name[1]);
            }
```

anyone is welcome using this code as long as he does not claim it for his~

the page query_params part is to properly instantiate it for a wordpress admin page. You can replace the cookie_domain string with anything you think will make it unique across your website so as two calls of the script for two tables wont mess each others data around (took me some time to figure that out)